# What's the differences between IKImageBrowserView's delegate and _delegate?

Tags: ikimagebrowserview, ikimagekit

[image]

As the picture says, there are delegate, _delegate, dataSource, _dataSource, what are the differences?

Basicly, I can use the functions I want with either delegate + dataSource or _delegate + _dataSource, but I don't know what the differences are?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the _delegate outlet is referencing the internal property directly whereas the delegate uses getters/setters.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you are right. So _delegate is the property while delegate means self.delegate? Why IKImageBrowserView need the two here?

Comment: You don't need to set both. Just use delegate and datasource (using it in my own project like this). The documentation does not say anything about the _delegate und _datasource versions: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/IKImageBrowserView